# query for same date, different years SQAlchemy

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a query that returns all the temperatures for the moth of June for every year in the database. I know how to get June temps for a specific year but not for all the years, here is my query for getting 2017s temps. Any ideas on how to do it for all the years in the database?

```
june_temps = session.query(Measurement.date, Measurement.tobs).filter(Measurement.date.between('2017-06-01','2017-06-30')).all()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Here the query you need: `select date, tobs from measurement where strftime('%m', date) = '06' order by 1` if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `extract` to get just the month == 6.
Documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.extract

```
from sqlalchemy import extract

session.query(Measurement.date,Measurement.tobs)\
       .filter(extract('month',Measurement.date)==6)\
       .all()
```

---

Full, tested example (different column name used for clarity):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, extract, Date, Integer, Column, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()


class Measurement(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'measurement'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    meas_date = Column(Date)
    meas_title = Column(String(64))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
session = Session()

meas1 = Measurement(meas_title='foo',meas_date=dt.date(2016,6,1))
meas2 = Measurement(meas_title='bar',meas_date=dt.date(2017,6,30))
meas3 = Measurement(meas_title='baz',meas_date=dt.date(2018,7,1))

session.add_all([meas1,meas2,meas3])
session.commit()

session.query(Measurement.id,Measurement.meas_date,Measurement.meas_title)\
       .filter(extract('month',Measurement.meas_date)==6)\
       .all()
```

Output:

```
Out[1]: [(1, datetime.date(2016, 6, 1), 'foo'), 
         (2, datetime.date(2017, 6, 30), 'bar')]
```